# nodejs parallel request sent using promise caused io exception

Tags: node.js, promise

I am using Promise in nodeJS to send parallel requests to external apis, because I want to increase the fetching speed. In Mac, it is good, all requests can be sent out in parallel, but in centos7 nodeJS, I noticed this error:

[Error: EIO, i/o error] errno: 55, code: 'EIO', syscall: 'write'

Why this exception happened?

This is the code I used:

```
var parallelFetcher = function(url, body, req, cb){
  var promises = [];
  var error = null;
  Object.keys(body).forEach(function(key){
    promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve){
      wrapper.post( url, JSON.parse(body[key]), req, function(err, data){
        if(!err)
          resolve(data);
        else
          error = err;
      })
    }));
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then(function(results){
    var keys = Object.keys(body);
    var resultObj = {};
    for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
      resultObj[keys[i]] = results[i];
    }
    cb(error, resultObj);
  }); 
}
```

Comment: What is `wrapper.post`?

Comment: Instead of setting `error`, you should call `reject`. Particularly, if you never settle the promise, `Promise.all` will be forever stuck pending.